# Numpy vectorized labeling of connected components

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision

I know how to find and label connected components using OpenCV or pure Python, but I was wondering if it was possible to use only Numpy to label connected components? If so, how could I implement it?

I've searched Google and StackOverflow, but could find no Numpy-only implementations of this. 4-way or 8-way connected components, either one would be great.

Here is an array that could be used for testing:

```
arr = np.array([
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
])
```

In this case, I would like the background to be 0, the large cross at the top left to all be 1, and the smaller cross on the right to all be 2.

Comment: Following similar pixels up and down, across rows, columns and diagonals isn't really something that lends itself to vectorisation like Numpy implements. What's your motivation for using Numpy? I presume you object equally to **scikit-image** `label()` here https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was thinking too, but sometimes I find beautiful roundabout vectorized solutions to problems that I had never imagined, and was wondering if this was one of those cases. My motivation was to try to remove as many dependencies as possible. Numpy is one that will have to remain because the performance difference between vectorized and non-vectorized operations is too great.